# Error message of class command not found in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("number of rooms:");
       int rooms = input.nextInt();
       int count = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < rooms; i++) {
           System.out.print("room capacity-q:");
           int q = input.nextInt();
           System.out.print("current space of the room-p:");
           int p = input.nextInt();
           if ((q - p) >= 2) {
               count += 1;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("no.rooms for thusitha & chamod is:"+count);
    }
}
```

I got an error called class not found.  want to know what are the reasons for that.

Comment: Which class is not found? Could it be a typo? Or a missed import?

Comment: Please show us the error.

Comment: I'm running this code without any errors...

Answer (score 0):

The code runs perfectly; causes no such error.
It would be better if you could provide with the details of the error you are getting.

Although i don't see any place to be wrong.
No aesthtic or typo errors are there in your code.
It gives one warning about the input scanner not being closed; which can be ignored for the time being.